# waiting for lock on .ivy2

Tags: sbt, ivy, typesafe-activator

I am using activator for cloning a project.

I made `eclipse.sbt` to prepare project to import to Eclipse. after typing `activator` in cmd I face waiting for lock on `C:\Users\Name\.ivy2\.sbt.ivy.lock to be available...`

I guess it is locking because of eclipse.sbt, if it is so how can I prevent it?

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Bueller? Where is the .lock file located?

Comment: @zero_cool hah, it was a longtime ago, I forgot to post the answer. but the fact is Activator has many bugs, specially with memory allocation. I shifted to SBT.

Comment: As for me this problem was resolved here: [Why would my play framework say wait for a .sbt lock to be available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578693/why-would-my-play-framework-say-wait-for-a-sbt-lock-to-be-available)

Answer (score 9):

Please check whether your IDE is downloading something, especially when you are running it your first time, it may take a while.

After the download is finished, you are able to run new command again!

Also, make sure you are not running 2 or more IDE or something, if that would not work, save your work and delete the lock file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, I was also getting the same error

```
Waiting for lock on C:\Users\ajain9\.ivy2\.sbt.ivy.lock to be available...
```

Then finally the issue was that there was another sbt process running on my system, and because of that the .sbt.ivy.lock file was not being available.lock file is used for synchronization purpose.

Once the previous process ended,I did not face this error again

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. The Reason being there was another process (IDE), which was performing a `sbt` operation.